# Is there something similar of windows "SetProcessWorkingSetSize" for linux?

Tags: kernel, google-chrome, performance, ram, cache

I run into a memory leak on google chrome when running my script as it sends clicks very fast.

I created an **example** code, in how to reproduce the leak on my post on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410135/chrome-memory-leak

Using Ubuntu after 1-hour sending clicks it goes over 3GB of ram in the page and keeps increasing constantly.

I found that setting a cap on the chrome process `Max working set size` solves the problem.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/increase-a-process-working-set

I would like to ask if someone knows if there's something similar on Linux?

Comment: suggest you change the title of your question to something meaningful to linux users. Myself, i don't know what windows terminology means. Anyway, if you are using systemd, then try `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=1G ./testm`, replacing `testm` with whatever.

Comment: I already tried `systemd-run`. When the process gets at the desired memory cap, it becomes unstable, freezing and not working correctly, the process is Google Chrome.